# Congratulations, amWhy hit 100k!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

Congratulations to @amWhy for hitting the 100k mark today.

As far as I know, she is the first woman to also reach this amazing milestone and we are lucky that she is a participant here!

Comment: female? How do you know?

Comment: Someone else mentioned and she has confirmed. In fact, amWhy is made up from her name Amy.

Comment: I offer a toast: based on what I have on hand, amWhy can choose between Dark 'n' Stormy, hard sparkling lemonade, Bailey's Original, or various wines or beers.

Comment: @dfeuer: I can add a mead and a pineapple(!) wine, neither of which I’ve yet tried, and an excellent French hard cider. And lots and lots of hops.

Comment: Congrats Amy! Your posts are always user-friendly, helpful and to the point. I will join @dfeuer, Brian and others to raise my glass (sparkling lemonade for me, please) :)

Comment: I downvote all these "congratulations" posts because I don't think they're interesting or useful and I would like to see fewer of them. This as I understand it is the purpose of downvoting in general. My votes are not intended as personal comments on the subjects of the posts.

Comment: Thanks to whoever took it upon him or herself to clean up this question by removing distracting comments, answers, and cross links. :)

Comment: Just ignore the celebration tag... @MJD

Comment: Do we have the second woman hitting the 100k mark? or maybe the third one?, since this is an old post..

Comment: @Isabella: Not that I know of, but it is certainly welcome!